# 2to3 range(...) -> list(range(...))

Tags: python, list, python-2to3

I know python 2to3 changes all `xrange` to `range` and I don't see any problem with this.  My question is about how it changes `range(...)` into `list(range(...))`: is it dumb and just blindly search and replaces them all, or is it smart enough to tell when the list isn't needed and leaving it as `range` would be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how intelligent it really is, but it certainly doesn't add `list()` to *every* `range()`.

For example, the following:

```
print(range(10))
```

is changed to:

```
print(list(range(10)))
```

However, the following:

```
for el in range(10):
  print(el)
```

is left untouched.

This clearly indicates that it's more sophisticated than a blind search-and-replace.

Comment: I noticed that if I rebind the name range to something else, and then use it later in the script, it still munges it.  So it can't be very intelligent ..

Comment: it also broke my doctests, because it ignored the xranges in those  :P